# Animate height from 50 to 10 but starting from 30 wpf

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a rectangle i want to animate the height of:

```
<Rectangle Height="30" Width="10" Fill="Black" Margin="10,0,10,0">
     <Rectangle.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Height)" From="50" To="10" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

this works great only i want the initial starting height of the rectangle to be 30. this code overrides the height and puts it to 50 when beginning the animation

Comment: Why do you want the initial Height to 30, if at the Loaded event (technically instantly) overwrite this with 50?

Comment: Remove `From="50"` from your animation? It's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: i want it to go from 30 to 10 then up to 50 then to 10 then to 50 then to 10 ect

Comment: @TóthTibor i did not know how else to apply the animation if i wanted it to be done instantly and continuously

Comment: sorry let me make that clearer, I want it to start at height of 30, animate down to 10. instantly set up to 50 then animate down to 10 and instantly set back to 50 and repeat. it will only be at 30 once but i need it to specifically start at a different value to 50 if this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second animation.

```
    <Rectangle Height="30"
               Width="10"
               Fill="Black"
               Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Height)"
                                         From="30"
                                         To="10"
                                         Duration="0:0:1"
                                         RepeatBehavior="1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Height)"
                                         From="50"
                                         To="10"
                                         Duration="0:0:1"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:1"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```